# Set language context for visualforce page dynamically

Tags: visualforce, translation

I need to set the language of my visualforce page dynamically in page controller,
But when I make some test
this works:

```
<apex:page Controller="PageController" language="en">
```

But with a variable, it does not work. I am sure the varaible contains value, for example : fr

```
<apex:page Controller="PageController" language="{!code}">
```

Please help me

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work"?

Comment: for example, if the variable = 'fr', the page still generated in English

Comment: Might be an API version problem - see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205219/apex-page-language-attribute-dynamic-assignment-strange-beahviour.

Comment: I tried api version 41, it does not work.

Comment: It worked for me when I did it a few months ago. Setting the language doesn't automatically translate everything on the page, just Field Labels, Picklist Options, and Custom Labels. You also have to verify in Translation Workbench that there is a value for the target language.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, here is the method I followed, off course, only custom labels, field labels are translated.https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8470/assign-language-value-dynamically-in-visualforce-page

Answer (score 0):

It is because I get TRANSLATED field labels' values, custom labels' value in page controller's constructor method. 
In the constructor method, i do

- initiate language code variable
- get translated field labels's value

According to the order of execution of visualforce page

1. Controllers + extentions
2. component's controller + extentions
3. assignTo functions for attributes
4. apex:page expression
   etc...

I did variable initialisation and calculation on controller's constructor which is the step 1, at this moment  expressions are not executed. so all returns labels are in english(default language ?)
its very important to understand the order of execution for VF in my case https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_lifecycle_example.htm