# How to get language from visualforce into into controller extension

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, controller-extension

I am using a force.com site to show a visualforce page where I want the user to have the option to select a language. In the corresponding visualforce page I set the language. How do I get this into my controller extension?

VFP:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="WebToObjAttachments" showHeader="false" language="nl_NL"  standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0" rendered="{!Id=null}" action="{!addMore}" >
```

Tried in extension

```
public class WebToObjAttachments {
..
 language = Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('language');
..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@sfdcfox is correct there is no way to get the page language from the page the way you have it set up, because its not a parameter. You can however dynamically set the page language by passing in the parameter. This question addresses this [Assign language Value dynamically in Visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8470/assign-language-value-dynamically-in-visualforce-page)

Answer (score 1):

The language attribute isn't a "page parameter" (those are strictly the values found in the URL after the `?`). As far as I'm aware, there's no way to get this information from the page. Similarly, there's no way to detect most of the other settings, such as determining if the page is being rendered as a PDF.

Comment: So should I add the parameter seperateley in the page as:    <apex:param name="language" value="nl_NL" assignTo="{!language}"/>. ?